# Android - Sound Stop Working Randomly

Tags: android, eclipse

My app consist of about 20 sounds files and its changes sound play by click. after random sound play its stop work for while and start again after some time or i have to close and run again.

Sometime it stops after 10 click, sometime stop after 40 clicks.

Comment: What phone are you using? How long are each sound? May it be cache full?

Comment: samsung tab3...its about 3 second each...but got intro sound in main

Comment: Try to empty cache and play sounds till they stop. Do you release mediaplayer everytime, right?

Comment: u mean empty cache on every click before play another sound?

Comment: Right. This way you shouldn't have problems if your problem is cache related.

Comment: ok thanks let me try! x

Comment: Did it work? If yes i make my answer so you can vote.